# Is there a way I can spread multiple rows into multiple columns?

Tags: r

I am a beginner R user so apologies if this is not quite fluent. I want to spread my data so that all variables for one Sample_file is in one row. My data (RW_leftjoin) currently looks something like this:

```
           Sample_File   Marker Peak Allele Height
 1: A02_1710963103.fsa     AMEL    1      X   5137
 2: A02_1710963103.fsa     AMEL    2      Y   4898
 3: A02_1710963103.fsa   CSF1PO    1     11    805
 4: A02_1710963103.fsa   CSF1PO    2     12    652
```

I want my data to look like this:

```
Sample_File          AMEL1 AMEL2 Height1 Height2 CSF1PO1 CSF1PO1 Height1 Height2
 1: A02_1710963103.fsa    X    Y    5137    4898    11    12      805    652
```

Is that possible using R?

I have tried using this:

```
RW_spread <- RW_leftjoin %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  group_by(Sample_File, Marker) %>%
  mutate(ID = paste0(Marker, Peak)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(ID, Allele)
```

but the data looks like this:

```
rowid Sample_File    Marker    Peak Height AMEL1 AMEL2 CSF1PO1 CSF1PO2
   <int> <chr>              <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
 1    1 A02_1710963103.fsa AMEL    1 5137    X    NA    NA      NA     
 2    2 A02_1710963103.fsa AMEL    2 4898   NA    Y     NA      NA     
 3    3 A02_1710963103.fsa CSF1PO    1 805    NA    NA    11    NA     
 4    4 A02_1710963103.fsa CSF1PO    2 652    NA    NA    NA    12
```

Would appreciate advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyr` approach is to `gather` the `Allele` and `Height` variables into a single column and create a key variable with the remaining columns (excluding the variable serving as an id) using `unite` and then `spread`ing the key/value pair.

```
library(tidyr) 

RW_leftjoin %>%
  gather(key, value, Allele, Height) %>%
  unite(tmp, c("Marker", "Peak", "key")) %>%
  spread(tmp, value)

         Sample_File AMEL_1_Allele AMEL_1_Height AMEL_2_Allele AMEL_2_Height CSF1PO_1_Allele CSF1PO_1_Height CSF1PO_2_Allele CSF1PO_2_Height
1 A02_1710963103.fsa             X          5137             Y          4898              11             805              12             652
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly, thank you! I didn't know about the ```unite``` function - that's so clever. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `tidyr`'s current development version (0.8.3.900) contains the function `pivot_wider`, which casts the data.frame to the desired wide format in a single function call (see also the vignette at [Tidyr: Pivoting](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html)):

```r
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, names_from = c("Marker", "Peak"), values_from = c("Allele", "Height"))

#>          Sample_File Allele_AMEL_1 Allele_AMEL_2 Allele_CSF1PO_1
#> 1 A02_1710963103.fsa             X             Y              11
#>   Allele_CSF1PO_2 Height_AMEL_1 Height_AMEL_2 Height_CSF1PO_1
#> 1              12          5137          4898             805
#>   Height_CSF1PO_2
#> 1             652

packageVersion("tidyr")
#> [1] '0.8.3.9000'
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Sample_File = c("A02_1710963103.fsa", "A02_1710963103.fsa", 
            "A02_1710963103.fsa", "A02_1710963103.fsa"), Marker = c("AMEL", 
            "AMEL", "CSF1PO", "CSF1PO"), Peak = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Allele = c("X", 
            "Y", "11", "12"), Height = c(5137L, 4898L, 805L, 652L)), row.names = c(NA, 
        -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I personally prefer `data.table` to the `tidyverse`, I would do

```
dcast(df,Sample_File~Marker+Peak,value.var=c("Allele","Height"))
```

what that command does is grouping the samples by Marker and Peak (`Sample_File~Marker+Peak`) and fill the table with values from Allele and Height (`value.var=c("Allele","Height")`)